# Can't activate venv in Pycharm Windows

Tags: python, pycharm, python-venv

I create venv project in Pycharm Windows and tried to activate it with running `venv\Scripts\activate.bat`

The output is

```
\OpenSSSH\\bin'";c:\Windows\System32\........was unexpected at this time.
```

That I see in terminal

```
(venv)....
```

And when I press `(venv) pip freeze` I see lot of packages that I didn't install in this project

But when I tried to pip install package I got message that this package is already install , that impossible because in venv there is not packages installed.

So why I can't activate venv?

Comment: Usually you select the environment you want to use under Settings -> Project -> Python interpreter (and select the `python.exe` in your venv); you don't need to activate it manually.

Comment: @MatsLindh Please look in my edit ,

Comment: I'm not sure what your edit changes; a `pip freeze` will include all packages installed by the packages you installed as well, so it'll include each and every package installed in your environment (not just those that you explicitly installed yourself).

Comment: @MatsLindh But it is new env. why do I see packages that I didn't install in this env. that why I this pycharm didn't activate my venv even I see `(venv)` in terminal